# WebSphere Liberty Server (IBM Bluemix) - error when run the RESTful web-service on server

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a maven RESTful web service application (with JAX-RS support). My API works perfectly when I run it on the Tomcat v7.0 server. However, I get an error when I deploy the same project on the WebSphere Liberty Server, which is used in Bluemix.

When I deploy the application, it loads without a problem. I am able to open the index.jsp page as well. It even runs perfectly for some of the API request calls (usually requests that do not take any input, do not produce output. However, for some of API requests it shows this error:

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.9/wlp-1.0.12.cl50920160227-1523) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_60-b27 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.9/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/congEst/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application congEst started in 11.912 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, wasJmsServer-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, javaMail-1.5, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jpa-2.1, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service:419'
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/HashMap; @90: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @90
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/   persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 015a b701 862a b401 5c2a b401
    0x0000010: 5ab6 0175 2ab4 015a b601 792a b401 5ab6
    0x0000020: 017b 2ab4 015a b601 782a b401 5ab6 0176
    0x0000030: 2ab4 015a b601 7db6 018d 57bb 00b2 59b7
    0x0000040: 016b 4ebb 00be 592d c000 c0b7 0195 3a04
    0x0000050: 1904 b601 943a 052d 1202 b601 6ac0 00b1
    0x0000060: 3a06 2ab4 015c b601 8a3a 0719 07b9 0198
    0x0000070: 0100 3a09 a700 5e19 09b9 019a 0100 c000
    0x0000080: 023a 08bb 009c 59bb 00a5 592b b801 62b7
    0x0000090: 0164 1201 b601 6519 08b6 016d b601 65b6
    0x00000a0: 0163 b701 5e3a 0a19 08b6 0170 3a0b 190b
    0x00000b0: 1300 9913 0098 b601 9319 0619 0bb9 01a2
    0x00000c0: 0200 1905 1908 bb00 9e59 190a b701 5fb6
    0x00000d0: 0196 1909 b901 9901 009a ff9e 2ab4 015c
    0x00000e0: b601 8bb0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@119,{Object[#182],Object[#164],Object[#170],Object[#176],Object[#190],Object[#191],Object[#177],Object[#167],Top,Object[#169]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@210)

at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:419)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/HashMap; @90: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @90
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/   persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 015a b701 862a b401 5c2a b401
    0x0000010: 5ab6 0175 2ab4 015a b601 792a b401 5ab6
    0x0000020: 017b 2ab4 015a b601 782a b401 5ab6 0176
    0x0000030: 2ab4 015a b601 7db6 018d 57bb 00b2 59b7
    0x0000040: 016b 4ebb 00be 592d c000 c0b7 0195 3a04
    0x0000050: 1904 b601 943a 052d 1202 b601 6ac0 00b1
    0x0000060: 3a06 2ab4 015c b601 8a3a 0719 07b9 0198
    0x0000070: 0100 3a09 a700 5e19 09b9 019a 0100 c000
    0x0000080: 023a 08bb 009c 59bb 00a5 592b b801 62b7
    0x0000090: 0164 1201 b601 6519 08b6 016d b601 65b6
    0x00000a0: 0163 b701 5e3a 0a19 08b6 0170 3a0b 190b
    0x00000b0: 1300 9913 0098 b601 9319 0619 0bb9 01a2
    0x00000c0: 0200 1905 1908 bb00 9e59 190a b701 5fb6
    0x00000d0: 0196 1909 b901 9901 009a ff9e 2ab4 015c
    0x00000e0: b601 8bb0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@119,{Object[#182],Object[#164],Object[#170],Object[#176],Object[#190],Object[#191],Object[#177],Object[#167],Top,Object[#169]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@210)

at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:480)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator.generateSchemaFiles(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/HashMap; @90: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/eclipse/persistence/core/sessions/CoreProject'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @90
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/compiler/Generator', 'java/lang/String', 'java/util/Map', 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'org/eclipse/   persistence/oxm/XMLContext', 'org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/XMLMarshaller' }
    stack: { 'org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/schema/SchemaModelProject', 'java/lang/Class' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2c 2ab4 015a b701 862a b401 5c2a b401
    0x0000010: 5ab6 0175 2ab4 015a b601 792a b401 5ab6
    0x0000020: 017b 2ab4 015a b601 782a b401 5ab6 0176
    0x0000030: 2ab4 015a b601 7db6 018d 57bb 00b2 59b7
    0x0000040: 016b 4ebb 00be 592d c000 c0b7 0195 3a04
    0x0000050: 1904 b601 943a 052d 1202 b601 6ac0 00b1
    0x0000060: 3a06 2ab4 015c b601 8a3a 0719 07b9 0198
    0x0000070: 0100 3a09 a700 5e19 09b9 019a 0100 c000
    0x0000080: 023a 08bb 009c 59bb 00a5 592b b801 62b7
    0x0000090: 0164 1201 b601 6519 08b6 016d b601 65b6
    0x00000a0: 0163 b701 5e3a 0a19 08b6 0170 3a0b 190b
    0x00000b0: 1300 9913 0098 b601 9319 0619 0bb9 01a2
    0x00000c0: 0200 1905 1908 bb00 9e59 190a b701 5fb6
    0x00000d0: 0196 1909 b901 9901 009a ff9e 2ab4 015c
    0x00000e0: b601 8bb0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@119,{Object[#182],Object[#164],Object[#170],Object[#176],Object[#190],Object[#191],Object[#177],Object[#167],Top,Object[#169]},{})
    same_frame_extended(@210)

at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1017)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:174)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:302)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:557)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:259)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1075)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:125)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
... 14 more

...
...
...
```

I can't figure out the problem. I searched in Google and realized that this problem (VerifyError) might happen if the compile time environment is different from runtime environment. However, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>vanet</groupId>
<artifactId>congEst</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>congEst</name>

<build>
    <finalName>congEst</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build> 

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
    <!-- <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId> -->
</dependency>
<!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>  
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jfuzzylogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>jFuzzyLogic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>



<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
</project>
```

This file is my `web.xml` file. If I want to remove the jersey implementation, what should I replace in this file?

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>vanet.congEst</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**UPDATE**

I have made the following changes and I am still getting an error.

```
-web.xml:
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>vanet.congEst</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

-pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>vanet</groupId>
    <artifactId>congEst</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>congEst</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>congEst</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 


    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jfuzzylogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>jFuzzyLogic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>  
   </project>
```

But I am getting this error when make a request to API.
Where is my mistake?

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, wasJmsServer-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, javaMail-1.5, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jpa-2.1, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [JAX-RS Servlet]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [JAX-RS Servlet]: com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet was found, but is missing another required class.
SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.
SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml you are referencing the JAX/RS implementation of Glassfish/Jersey. This is no problem in Tomcat, because Tomcat is only a Servlet container, but Liberty is a full JEE application server, that comes with its own JAX/RS implementation based on Apache CXF and Jackson.

So first I would recommend that you install Liberty also locally to test your code before you ship it into Bluemix. Just go to [liberty's download page](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/).

Then you should remove all your Glassfish dependencies and change your pom.xml to use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is plain JEE and has no dependency on any vendor specific code. Look at [this simple pom.xml](https://github.com/giraone/simple-jaxrs/blob/master/pom.xml). This would run in Liberty on Bluemix.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I removed all Glassfish dependecies but it show this error:  
[ERROR   ] SRVE8052E: Logging ClassNotFoundException
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
[ERROR   ] SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [Jersey Web Application]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer]: Could not find required class - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1578)
 at [internal classes]

Comment: I have put my web.xml file too. can u plz tell how can I modify this file to remove jersey implementation.?

Comment: That error indicates you are directly referencing jersey classes in your application. You shouldn't need to do this, let JAX-RS annotations do the work for you.

Comment: @ebullient I have removed jersey and now Im using JAX-RS. I am using IBMRestServlet as my servlet in web.xml file (updated above FYI). but now im getting this error: `Servlet [JAX-RS Servlet]: com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet was found, but is missing another required class.`  can u plz tell me what are those dependencies which it is missing?

Comment: With either version of JAX-RS, you don't need that at all. Remove the `<init-param></init-param>` and `<servlet-class></servlet-class>` stanzas from your web.xml entirely.

You don't actually need web.xml at all for JAX-RS endpoints, you can set up everything using an `@ApplicationPath` annotation on a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, as shown here: https://github.com/WASdev/sample.async.jaxrs/blob/master/async-jaxrs-application/src/main/java/net/wasdev/jaxrs/async/AsyncJaxrsApplication.java

Comment: @gira, is this problem solved?